# Switching views without first view being reset

Tags: ios, iphone, view

I'm making a role-playing game, and I want to have a Map View and a Battle Screen. With the possibility of other screens as well.

I thought the best way to achieve this was to use multiple NIB files.

When I prototyped this by have one view that creates content, switching to the next view, and then back, the content on the original view was reset.

How do I make it so that the first view doesn't reset the data each time it's loaded?

Comment: Where/how are your view controllers created?

Comment: The view controllers use the AppDelegate to transition from Nib to Nib.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little vague. A view usually does not get "reset" unless you run into a low memory warning. That said, even then it's just up to you to keep the right references and setup your view correctly. Maybe have a read through [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationEnvironment/ApplicationEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW49) or provide some code. Adrian also has a [good write-up](http://akosma.com/2009/01/28/10-iphone-memory-management-tips/) about this.

Comment: I assume you have a view controller per NIB. Make sure you keep their references around.

Comment: Just retain them through an ivar/propterty.